# Add textbox to each date in calendar

Tags: c#, calendar

In the following calendar example, if I select multiple or range of calendar days and enter a text, 1 textbox control get added through all selected days, same as in outlook. how can't make the calender enter a seperate textbox control with same text on each day insead of merging all of them into one textbox ? thank you

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38699/A-Professional-Calendar-Agenda-View-That-You-Will

```
public void CreateItemOnSelection(string itemText, bool editMode)
{
    if (SelectedElementEnd == null || SelectedElementStart == null) return;

    CalendarTimeScaleUnit unitEnd = SelectedElementEnd as CalendarTimeScaleUnit;
    CalendarDayTop dayTop = SelectedElementEnd as CalendarDayTop;
    CalendarDay day = SelectedElementEnd as CalendarDay;
    TimeSpan duration = unitEnd != null ? unitEnd.Duration : new TimeSpan(23, 59, 59);
    CalendarItem item = new CalendarItem(this);

    DateTime dstart = SelectedElementStart.Date;
    DateTime dend = SelectedElementEnd.Date;

    if (dend.CompareTo(dstart) < 0)
    {
        DateTime dtmp = dend;
        dend = dstart;
        dstart = dtmp;
    }

    item.StartDate = dstart;
    item.EndDate = dend.Add(duration);
    item.Text = itemText;

    CalendarItemCancelEventArgs evtA = new CalendarItemCancelEventArgs(item);

    OnItemCreating(evtA);

    if (!evtA.Cancel)
    {
        Items.Add(item);

        if (editMode)
        {
            _creatingItem = true;
            ActivateEditMode(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what issues are you experiencing..? does the code provided in the link that you have attached do what you need..? if not please clarify the what, where and why in your code that things are not happening as expected..

Comment: the attached link work perfectly in case of selecting mutiple days and adding 1 textbox control. How can I modifier the code to be able to enter a seperate textbox control into each cell in calender when I select multiple days.

Comment: you can step through the code and understand the `What, Where, How, and Why` it's adding 1 textbox, follow that same logic and implement your own method to add multiple textboxes this is something that you will need to step through and understand. I would suggest trying something first then report back on why things are not working based on some coded example of refactoring the code and or adding additional functionality.. that's what programming is about